# what is the value of y in additive time series decomposition

Tags: geology, geophysics

I understand the additive time series formula is y = trend + Seasonal + cyclic + residual. But what is the value of y. Is it the the combination of trend, seasonal , cyclic and residual which is shown on first row of the graph below and we get value of trend and ger second row graph using trend = y - seasonal - cyclic-residual and so forth?
[image]

Comment: The plots look like the result of fitting to a model, where the model is the sum  trend + seasonal + cyclic. The difference between the "best fit" model and the actual data (y) is the residuals. This is the usual conceptual approach unless you are performing a simulation, in which case the residuals are noise added purposely to the model to make it look like real data.